# Gitlab master access level

Tags: gitlab

I have a Gitlab group (**testgroup**) also I have the project (**testproject**). Now the testproject is in the testgroup.

What would happen if I added A group (**testgroup**) master as a **developer** in the inside of the project?

Would they able to accept the merge request for the particular project?

How could I add the group master as a developer in the same group's project?

Answer (score 2):

Someone who is declared a group master is *not* a project Master, even if that project is in the group

See [Group permission](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/permissions.md#group): he or she only has the additional privilege of creating projects in the group.

Comment: I know it, But want to know what will happen who declared the group master as the project developer which the project in the group

Comment: @Arunald I suspect any member of that group would be developer for that project